MySQL 8.0 Query to MariaDB
I created the following query in MySQL 8.0, but when I try to add using phpMyAdmin I get the following error:

MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WITH RECURSIVE t as ( select CAST(DATE_FORMAT(selectedDT ,'%Y-%m-01') as...' at line 3

question: How can I convert the query to MariaDB?
the query:
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`PROCEDURE`stats_getbycurrmonth\`(in selectedDT DateTime)
BEGIN
SET @lastday = last_day(CONCAT(year(selectedDT),'-',month(selectedDT),'-01'));

WITH RECURSIVE t as (
select CAST(DATE_FORMAT(selectedDT ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE) as dt
UNION
SELECT DATE_ADD(t.dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY) FROM t WHERE DATE_ADD(t.dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY) \<= @lastday
)

SELECT Y.*, R.* FROM
(SELECT count(\*) as COUNT, date(dataora) as DAY FROM dinaromdb.loguri where nivel like '%ERROR%' group by date(dataora) order by date(dataora)
) R RIGHT JOIN
(select date(dt) as Days, dayname(dt) as DayName FROM t
) Y on R.Day = Y.Days GROUP BY Y.Days, Y.DayName, R.COUNT;
END

execution:
call dinaromdb.stats_getbycurrmonth('2024-11-05');
preview:

what I tried:
Based on this article I tried to remove the "recursive" keyword, but without luck.

Apart from two \ I do not see any other syntax errors. See https://dbfiddle.uk/ujBacCQq

What's your mariadb version?

Looks like you forget to reassign a delimiter.

PS. What is the reason to use separate statement for user-defined variable creation/assigning if this variable is used only once? Move the expression into the query and remove SET statement and BEGIN-END keywords, single-statement CREATE PROCEDURE does not need in them. https://dbfiddle.uk/rCvpxgZl

On a side note: The last day of the month is the last day of the month, no matter whether you feed LAST_DAY with the first day or any other day of the month. So, last_day(CONCAT(year(selectedDT),'-',month(selectedDT),'-01')) can be replaced by a simple last_day(selectedDT).

On another side note: Don't use RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN. Queries with right joins are often very hard to read. Always put jour joins in such an order that you can use a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN instead.

And stop thinking in strings when its really about dates and datetimes. Don't CAST(DATE_FORMAT(selectedDT ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE), but DATE(selectedDT).

@ThorstenKettner That doesn't get the first day of the month. Did you miss the -01 in the format string?

@Barmar: LAST_DAY gives us the last day of the month. Let's say they have '2024-12-18 00:00:00', then the last day is '2024-12-31'. For unknown reasons, though, they change the 18th to the 1st and ask for the last day for '2024-12-01', which of course is still '2024-12-31'.

@ThorstenKettner I was referring to select CAST(DATE_FORMAT(selectedDT ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE) as dt. There's no FIRST_DAY() function for this.

@Barmar: Oops. Yes, I missed that. True, MariaDB lacks a function to truncate a date to the first day of the month, so one cannot help but muddle through. :-)

The date/time function for "FIRST_DAY" could be DATE_SUB(@selectDT, INTERVAL  DAY(@selectDT)-1 DAY).  (I too have mild "as string" phobia for dates).

@Akina I didn't test on the production server, but on the test server after adding DELIMITER $$ CREATE and END$$ DELIMITER ; works using the phpMyAdmin->SQL tab. this is on 10.6.18 version. Tomorrow I will test on the production too, hope it works.
